# Binding to a started Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-service-binding

I have a remote Service that I start with startService() then bind to with bindService().  I do this because I want the Service to run in the background until the app explicitly stops it, even if the user closes the Activity with a swipe.  Here are the relevant parts of the Service:

```
public class TrackService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("onStartCommand","got to onStartCommand");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("onBind", "got to onBind");
        return trackServiceBinder;
    }
}
```

Here is the activity:

```
public class GPSLoggerActivity extends Activity implements ServiceConnection {

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Intent intent = new Intent(TrackService.class.getName());
        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), TrackService.class);

        startService(intent);
        Log.i("onStart", "started TrackService");

        if (!getApplicationContext().bindService(intent, this, 0)) {
            // close the Activity
        }

        Log.i("onStart", "bound to TrackService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.i("onServiceConnected", "got here");

        // get and use the interface from the Binder
    }
}
```

Here is the manifest for the Service:

```
    <service
        android:name=".TrackService"
        android:process=":track_service_process"
        android:stopWithTask="false"
        android:label="@string/track_service_label"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mydomain.gpslogger.TrackService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

When I run this in the debugger step-wise through startService() and bindService() everything is fine.  Within the Service, onStartCommand() is invoked followed by onBind(), and in the Activity onServiceConnected() is invoked with the Binder.  However, when I'm not debugging, for some reason the Service gets its onBind() method invoked **before** its onStartCommand() method.  Here's the output from the log:

```
11-28 23:17:01.805: I/onStart(1103): started TrackService
11-28 23:17:01.815: I/onStart(1103): bound to TrackService
11-28 23:17:01.985: I/onBind(1165): got to onBind
11-28 23:17:01.995: I/onStartCommand(1165): got to onStartCommand
```

The Activity's onServiceConnected() method is never invoked.  I've tried using BIND_AUTO_CREATE in the bindService() call, to no effect.  It's pretty clear I have some sort of race condition going on here, but I've run this probably 20 times and it always comes out in the same order.  The only way I can think of to enforce the correct order of calls in the Service is to put a BroadcastReceiver in the Activity and send an Intent from the onStartCommand() method of the Service to let the Activity know that it's time to call bindService().  That seems pretty kludgy...is there a better way to do this?  Or is there something that I'm missing that is causing the out-of-order calls?

Comment: your service is running into a different process...have you tried using android:exported="true"?

Comment: Doesn't affect it. I think the exported attribute allows other apps to see the service... even though this is a different process it's the same app. I implemented the kludge fix I proposed in the question and it works.  Still seems like there should be a more elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

You could call `startService()` and then wait some period of time before calling `bindService()`. How long to wait is certainly a question, but I would think if your `Service` doesn't do massive amounts of work when started, 500 or 1000 milliseconds delay should do it.

I would question why this is important. The `Service` has an `onCreate()` method, which is called when the `Service` is instantiated, regardless of whether `onStartCommand()` or `onBind()` is called first. You should be able to setup your architecture so that you do all important setup in `onCreate()` and then it shouldn't matter in what order `onStartCommand()` or `onBind()` is called. NOTE: You must use flag `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` in the call to `bindService()`

I also do not understand why the `onServiceConnected()` method is not called. Unless the call to `bindService()` returns `false` (which basically means that Android can't find the `Service` to bind to), you should get the `onServiceConnected()` callback. This sounds strange. One possibility is that the `Service` crashes in `onCreate()`, or it takes too long to execute the `onCreate()` method, in which case Android will declare the `Service` broken.