# Why android bound service is not started after crash?

Tags: android

I had a crash problem at the start of the service. The problem is fixed, but I started to wonder why the system doesn't keep trying to pick up such a **bound service** if it has defined:

```
class TestService : Service() {
    ...
    override fun onStartCommand(
        intent: Intent?,
        flags: Int,
        startId: Int
    ): Int {
        return START_STICKY
    }
    ...
}
```

Service is defined in AndoridManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:name="com.TestApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:persistent="false"
    tools:ignore="MissingApplicationIcon">
    <service
        android:name=".TestService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.TEST_SERVICE" />
</application>
```

My analysis shows that the system tries to raise such a service twice and that's it. Later, after a long time, system also makes a one-time attempt. I tested it on Andorid 9 and Andorid 10.

It's hard to find information on the internet on this subject. Has anyone had experiences and knows exactly how the system behaves in this situation?

Comment: You need to start the service via `Context.startService` or `Context.startForegroundService`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I forgot to add that it is bound service and other app binds to the service, which crashes during startup.

Answer (score 0):

I found some details here:
https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/components/bound-services.html

"When the last client unbinds from the service, the system destroys the service (unless the service was also started by startService())."

and here:
[Binding to a started Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199274/binding-to-a-started-service)

"You could call startService() and then wait some period of time before calling bindService(). How long to wait is certainly a question, but I would think if your Service doesn't do massive amounts of work when started, 500 or 1000 milliseconds delay should do it.

I would question why this is important. The Service has an onCreate() method, which is called when the Service is instantiated, regardless of whether onStartCommand() or onBind() is called first. You should be able to setup your architecture so that you do all important setup in onCreate() and then it shouldn't matter in what order onStartCommand() or onBind() is called. NOTE: You must use flag BIND_AUTO_CREATE in the call to bindService()

I also do not understand why the onServiceConnected() method is not called. Unless the call to bindService() returns false (which basically means that Android can't find the Service to bind to), you should get the onServiceConnected() callback. This sounds strange. One possibility is that the Service crashes in onCreate(), or it takes too long to execute the onCreate() method, in which case Android will declare the Service broken."

Because of crash during startup, no client can bind to the service. Do I understand correctly that this is how the system interprets such a situation and kills Service process as broken?